# Popup box like query in window application

Tags: c#, notifications, window

I am working on window based application in C#. Every thing is working fine. I just want to show notification message and its working, Can i show that notification message like Jquery fancy dialog box ?
 Is there any third party took, like telrix, ajax etc. which show me message like jquery fancy dialog box.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Like a 'toast' popup? There are several articles on CodeProject showing this.

Comment: Yes there are many. What effects do you want to use, fade in can be programmed so easily I wouldn't use an external library for that.

Comment: yes, i want to use like fade in/fadeout message box. could you provide me any refernce link. I want to show notification message.like gtalk when any mail comes it show message in right-bottom corner.